# PHP with podman shows internal ip address as remote address

Tags: php, docker, nginx, podman

I run a simple nginx, php server with docker on a remote server. I call a url which display my remote address:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

And I see my real public ip address. But if I run the exactly same project with podman instead docker, the url shows an internal ip address:

```
10.89.0.3
```

How can I do with podman, to show the real remote address?

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: min-web-nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    depends_on:
      - php
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - halozat
  php:
    container_name: min-web-php
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    networks:
      - halozat
networks:
  halozat:
```

Comment: If I create a pod with this command, the nginx log shows the correct remote address:

`podman run -p 8080:80 --network slirp4netns:port_handler=slirp4netns docker.io/library/nginx:latest`

But I don't now how can I apply this in docker-compose.yml